# Question about notation on the NIST DLMF

Tags: notation, reference-works

Many relations on the [NIST DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/) have certain restriction on parameters that must be satisfied in order for the relation to hold.  Take for example [equation $15.8.5$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E5) which lists multiple constraints on the variable $z$, namely, $|\mathrm{ph}\, z|<\pi,\,|\mathrm{ph}\,(1-z)|<\pi$.

My question is if the constraints should be read as an "and" or "or" statement.  Going back to the example, should I interpret the constraints as
$$|\mathrm{ph}\, z|<\pi\quad \textbf{and}\quad |\mathrm{ph}\,(1-z)|<\pi$$
or
$$|\mathrm{ph}\, z|<\pi\quad \textbf{or}\quad |\mathrm{ph}\,(1-z)|<\pi?$$

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think it means "or".  If you look at the formulas in [15.6](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6), they use a semicolon in contexts where "and" is intended.  (Or at least I think so.)

Comment: @saulspatz I am starting to think is does mean "and" see http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9.E3.  It would seem the integral requires both criteria to be satisfied to converge.  That said, I am still not fully convinced yet.

Comment: It looks like they weren't fully consistent then.  What a shame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $|\mathrm{ph}\, z|<\pi$ means that there is
a branch cut for reals less than $0$.
The condition $|\mathrm{ph}\, (1-z)|<\pi$ means that there is a branch cut
for reals greater than $1$.
The context is that **both** of these branch cuts
are to be excluded and thus the "," is to be interpreted as "and".